# Writing Spark Structure Streaming data into Cassandra fails due to Assertion Failure

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-structured-streaming

I want to write Structure Streaming Dataset into Cassandra. I use watermark in the script and I use a similar code used
at: https://github.com/polomarcus/Spark-Structured-Streaming-Examples
or 
https://github.com/fhuertas/cassandra-sink-spark-structured-streaming
to sink the data.

The flow of the script is: 
Kafka -> watermark event time -> groupBy -> sink to Cassandra

```
    val counts= words
        .withWatermark("eventTime", "60 seconds")
        .groupBy(
            window($"eventTime","60 seconds", "30 seconds"),
            $"word")
        .count()

    val query= counts
        .writeStream
        .format("streamsinkprovider.CassandraSinkProvider")
        .outputMode("append")
        .start()
```

and I tried two approaches for sink:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._

df.select("word","count").as[(String,BigInt)]
    .write
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .cassandraFormat("test", CassandraLibrary.CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE)
    .save()
```

and

```
 ds.rdd.saveToCassandra(
        CassandraLibrary.CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE, 
        "test", SomeColumns("word","count"), cassandraWriteConf)
```

In both cases I get below exception:

> java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No plan for
>   EventTimeWatermark eventTime#272: timestamp, interval 1 minutes

It seems saveToCassandra tries to create a RDD and that causes spark to create a new plan.

JDBC sink (mysql) works well with no error for the same code.

I have tried this with Spark Version 2.2.0 and 2.3.2 and datastax.spark-cassandra-connector 2.0.5 and 2.3.2. I tried with DSE Cassandra 5.1 and Apache Cassandra 3.11

Any idea how to get around this issue?

Comment: Can you add the specific spark code? It would make recreating the issue easier.

Comment: Sure, post edited with more details.